# XSLTProcessor output cut by half

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

I have a unsolvable problem (of course, from my point of view).

I always get *XSLTProcessor.transformToFragment* output reduced in half in comparison to the input size.

E.g. I have 200 entries as the response of webservice in XML file, which is been transformed into table with a header. These 200 entries result in a table that has always 100 + 1(header) rows.
I have tried to slice input XML file into two with 100 input entries and got 50+1 rows.
I do a client side transformation. I use JavaScript, Jquery, Chrome plugin for IntelliJ Idea for debug and there is no difference if I debbug or just run code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th style="text-align:left">qqq</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">qqq</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">qqq</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">qqq</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">qqq</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">qqq</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">qqq</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="SearchTour_PRICES/prices/price">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="checkIn"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="nights"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="town"/>
                    </td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="hotel"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="star"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="meal"/>
                    </td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="room"/>,&#160;<xsl:value-of select="htPlace"/>
                    </td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="currency"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: xslUrl,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xsl) {

if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
{
    return xmlData.transformNode(xsl);
}
else
if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
    xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
    resultfragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlData, document);
    return resultfragment;
}
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Here is an example of input xml. Ordinary service response contains 200 *price* nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SearchTour_PRICES>
  <prices>
    <price>
      <id>0x0100167AA20000000200000006A2D3000000000003000000000000000D00004093000000040000000500000073000000000000000000000001</id>
      <claim>1473186</claim>
      <checkIn>20140215</checkIn>
      <checkOut>20140228</checkOut>
      <nights>13</nights>
      <adult>1</adult>
      <child>0</child>
      <tour>Antalya for online</tour>
      <tourAlt>Тур в Анталию для онлайна</tourAlt>
      <tourKey>3</tourKey>
      <tourRequest>0</tourRequest>
      <tourUrl></tourUrl>
      <programType>Стандарт</programType>
      <programTypeAlt>Standard</programTypeAlt>
      <programTypeKey>1</programTypeKey>
      <programTypeUrl></programTypeUrl>
      <partnerIncoming>Travel Profi</partnerIncoming>
      <partnerIncomingAlt>Принимающая сторона Тура</partnerIncomingAlt>
      <partnerIncomingKey>31667</partnerIncomingKey>
      <town>Antalya</town>
      <townAlt>Анталия</townAlt>
      <townKey>5</townKey>
      <hotel>Adora Golf Resort</hotel>
      <hotelAlt>Adora Golf Resort</hotelAlt>
      <hotelKey>16531</hotelKey>
      <star>*****</star>
      <starAlt>*****</starAlt>
      <starKey>5</starKey>
      <meal>UAI</meal>
      <mealAlt>UAI</mealAlt>
      <mealKey>115</mealKey>
      <mealNote></mealNote>
      <mealUrl></mealUrl>
      <room>STD ROOM</room>
      <roomAlt>STD ROOM</roomAlt>
      <roomKey>4</roomKey>
      <htPlace>SNGL</htPlace>
      <htPlaceAlt>SNGL</htPlaceAlt>
      <htPlaceKey>5</htPlaceKey>
      <price>601</price>
      <currency>USD</currency>
      <currencyKey>2</currencyKey>
      <convertedPrice>18030 RUB</convertedPrice>
      <convertedCurrencyKey>1</convertedCurrencyKey>
      <spo></spo>
      <spoKey>0</spoKey>
      <spoNote></spoNote>
      <stopSale></stopSale>
      <stopSpog></stopSpog>
      <packetType>0</packetType>
      <hotelUrl>http://192.168.0.38/tour/hotels?samo_action=hotel&amp;HOTELINC=16531</hotelUrl>
      <attributes>
        <attribute>
          <id>57</id>
          <name>Рекомендуем</name>
          <note>Мы очень рекомендуем вам этот отель, ибо он нам дает большую комиссию</note>
          <icon>http://192.168.0.38/tour/data/hotelparam/hp_57_56702547.png</icon>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
          <id>59</id>
          <name>Семейный</name>
          <note></note>
          <icon>http://192.168.0.38/tour/data/hotelparam/hp_59_56702549.png</icon>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
          <id>60</id>
          <name>Молодежный</name>
          <note></note>
          <icon>http://192.168.0.38/tour/data/hotelparam/hp_60_56702550.png</icon>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
          <id>61</id>
          <name>Активный</name>
          <note></note>
          <icon>http://192.168.0.38/tour/data/hotelparam/hp_61_56702551.png</icon>
        </attribute>
      </attributes>
      <listTime>18:00, 22:30</listTime>
      <bron>1</bron>
      <momentConfirm></momentConfirm>
      <crossTour>0</crossTour>
      <best>0</best>
      <paymentschedule>0</paymentschedule>
      <stats>1</stats>
      <color>white</color>
      <freights>
        <econom>
          <in>Y</in>
          <out>Y</out>
        </econom>
        <busines>
          <in>Y</in>
          <out>Y</out>
          <surcharge>
            <in>
              <price>100</price>
              <currencyAlias>USD</currencyAlias>
              <currencyKey>2</currencyKey>
              <converted>3000 RUB</converted>
            </in>
            <out>
              <price>100</price>
              <currencyAlias>USD</currencyAlias>
              <currencyKey>2</currencyKey>
              <converted>3000 RUB</converted>
            </out>
            <total>
              <price>200</price>
              <currencyAlias>USD</currencyAlias>
              <currencyKey>2</currencyKey>
              <converted>6000 RUB</converted>
            </total>
          </surcharge>
        </busines>
        <comfort>
          <in>Y</in>
          <out>Y</out>
        </comfort>
        <premium>
          <in>N</in>
          <out>N</out>
        </premium>
      </freights>
      <townFrom>2</townFrom>
      <state>6</state>
      <note></note>
    </price>
  </prices>
</SearchTour_PRICES>
```

Comment: How do you get `xmlData`?

Comment: If it is always half, can you test with 2 entries and find if you receive 1 + 1, or 1 + 2 rows? Are you testing the result of rows how they are rendered, or physically checking the (X)HTML generated and counting `<tr>`? Can you compare the result by doing the same transform, but dumping it in a textbox so you can compare rendered vs. actual?

Comment: Zealander, I get it via ajax http request from remote webservice.

Comment: @Abel, I got what you suggest. Will try with smaller number of entries. I render it with Chrome plugin and also check with find(selector). Renderded result and debug watches are equal

Comment: If you have a place where we can see the full page in action, since this is rendered client-side, we could have a look. Certainly, no XSLT processor I know of (and I think I have worked with almost all) have ever shown this kind of behavior.

Comment: @a.yanyev , it's possible that if your ajax calls follow one another, the second one (the xsl) starts working before the first one finishes loading the xml entirely. Especially if you have such an enormous XML. Please post your full function. Or you can try nesting ajax calls: call the XSL ajax from within XML ajax `success`.

Comment: Thank you, guys!!! Your advices made me dig deeper. I've used wrong xPath to control input size - '//price' instead of '//prices/price'. There is one more 'price' element deeper in xml structure )))
Anyway, you gave me neccessary impact

Comment: This webservice is one of the numerous implementations of commercial product. Docs say that it returns 200 price items per request but this implemantation actually returns only 100. That circumstace confused me all that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used wrong xPath to control input size - '//price' instead of '//prices/price'. There is one more 'price' element deeper in xml structure